# Linux I2C: read length of message

Tags: c, linux, i2c

TL;DR: How to read a I2C message, as a master, where the message length is received first?

I have a I2C slave (SL030) connected to my Linux system. When the I2C slaves needs to send a message, i waits till a read request is made and then sends the length of the message and then the message data.
A message looks like this:

```
+------+   +-------+   +--------+     +--------+
| 0xA1 | - | len n | - | data 0 | ... | data n |
+------+   +-------+   +--------+     +--------+
```

The `0xA1` is the slave address+read bit and comes from the master, everything else comes from the slave. I am not able to make my system read `len` byte when `len` is variable.

I tried it using `ioctl()` with `I2C_RDWR` and `I2C_M_RECV_LEN`. The amount of read bytes is always the same.

Here is my testing code. Sorry for the length, i tried to make it shorter.

```
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
#include <linux/i2c.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#include <errno.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct I2c_T
{
  int fd;    //file descriptor
  int slave; //slave address
};

struct I2c_packet_T
{
  uint8_t len;
  uint8_t data[256];
};

static void die(const char *str)
{
  perror(str);
  exit(1);
}

static void i2c_sendPacket(struct I2c_T *self, struct I2c_packet_T *packet)
{
  unsigned char data[packet->len+1];
  data[0]=packet->len;
  memcpy(data+1,packet->data,packet->len);
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)  //Try writing it 3 times, because there could be a hardware problem
  {
    if(write(self->fd,packet->data,packet->len)>=0)
    {
      return; //success
    }
    usleep(100);
  }
  die("can not write i2c data");
}

static void i2c_getPacket(struct I2c_T *self, struct I2c_packet_T *packet)
{
  uint8_t buffer[1024]={8}; //it always reads buffer[0] byte and doesn't work when it is 0
  struct i2c_msg msg=
  {
    .addr  = self->slave,
    .flags = I2C_M_RECV_LEN | I2C_M_RD,
    .len   = 65, //must be at least 32+buffer[0] otherwise it does not work
    .buf   = buffer
  };
  struct i2c_rdwr_ioctl_data data={&msg,1};
  bool success;
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)  //Try reading it 3 times, because there could be a hardware problem
  {
    usleep(100);
    if(ioctl(self->fd,I2C_RDWR,&data)>=0)
    {
      success=1;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(!success)
  {
    die("Can not get packet");
  }
  fprintf(stderr,"data is len %"PRIu16", data:",msg.len);
  for(unsigned i=0;i<msg.len+32;i++)
  {
    fprintf(stderr," %02"PRIx8"",msg.buf[i]);
  }
  fprintf(stderr,"\n");
  memcpy(packet->data,msg.buf,msg.len);
}

void i2c_handlePacket
  (struct I2c_T *self, struct I2c_packet_T *sendPacket, struct I2c_packet_T *receivePacket)
{
  i2c_sendPacket(self,sendPacket);
  i2c_getPacket(self,receivePacket);
}



void i2c_test(const char *path, uint8_t slave)
{
  struct I2c_T self;
  self.fd=-1;
  self.slave=slave;

  self.fd = open(path, O_RDWR);
  if(self.fd<0)
  {
    die("can not open i2c device");
  }
  if(ioctl(self.fd,I2C_SLAVE,self.slave)<0)
  {
    die("can not set i2c address");
  }
  struct I2c_packet_T send={2,{1,1}};
  struct I2c_packet_T receive={0};
  i2c_handlePacket(&self,&send,&receive);
  close(self.fd);
}

int main(void)
{
  i2c_test("/dev/i2c-1",0x50);
}
```

The amount of bytes read is 8, as i see with my logic analyzer, regardless of the message length indicated by the slave. I tried different flags, different length and made other tests but no success so far.

I am on Debian 9 (stretch) on a Raspberry Pi 3B.

Comment: The I2C driver takes care of sending the address byte specified by I2C_SLAVE.  I2C_RDWR is for combined read/write transactions, not normal reads.

Comment: @stark the problem is not the slave number, this works fine. The problem is that my master ignores the length specified by the slave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the datasheet of the BCM2708 i see that this is not possible with this hardware and this is not a driver problem.

A solution could be to bit bang I2C in software, but this is not very efficient on a user space program. For a kernel module see here https://github.com/kadamski/i2c-gpio-param

I ended up just reading 256 byte and ignore unused bytes in software.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to communicate with I²C device via SMBus host controller...